# Case statement:Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, case, multiple-columns, flags

I am writing a query like this

```
select case @flag
when 'Y' then (select * from some table which is having multiple column)
when 'N' then (select * from some table which is having multiple column)
end
as Result
,@flag:='Y'
```

but it is showing `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`.
I Know that `case` can only return one column but just want to know if any way is available for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select a column in the subqueries:

```
select (case @flag
            when 'Y' then (select col from some table which is having multiple column)
----------------------------------^
            when 'N' then (select col from some table which is having multiple column)
        end) as Result,
       @flag:='Y'
```

Comment: Hi Gordon
Please have a look into the question now.Previously it was having one silly mistake there.

Comment: @NavneetNandanJha . . . You need to select *one* column in the subqueries.

Comment: If I want to select multiple column then How should I proceed?

Comment: @NavneetNandanJha . . . Use a `join` or multiple `case` statements, one for each column.